# Welche Bedeutung von »schier« ist hier gemeint?

Tags: meaning, adjective

In Braunschweig gibt es eine Straße [Unter den Schieren Bäumen](http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/22999090).

Soweit mir bisher bekannt war, kann *schier* eines von zwei Sachen bedeuten:

- [Fast, nahezu](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schier_fast_nahezu)

  > Das ist schier unmöglich!
- [rein, unvermischt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schier_blosz_genuin_pur)

  > Allein durch seine schiere Größe überragte der Turm die Landschaft.

Beide Bedeutungen scheinen hier nicht zu passen (»unter den fast-Bäumen«? »unter den reinen Bäumen«?) – zumal ich die zweite Bedeutung bisher fast ausschließlich mit substantivierten Adjektiven gelesen hab. Das Dudenbeispiel »schieres Fleisch« habe ich so nicht gekannt, aber es ist in sich schlüssig, und es hilft meines Erachtens nicht viel für die Erklärung der Bäume – oder sollen es etwa Bäume sein, unter denen keine Büsche wachsen oder kein Gras wächst?

Weiß jemand mehr?

Comment: Ich glaube, da hast du fast mehr Glück im Rathaus/ Stadtplanungsamt nachzufragen wie die Benennung der Straßen in dem Gebiet durchgeführt wurden. Wahrscheinlich gibt es da irgendeinen Bezug, der im modernen Deutsch nicht mehr offensichtlich ist.

Comment: Glaube nicht, dass es sich hier um das normale Adjektiv schier handelt. Das kann ein Eigenname, ein Stadtviertel oder sonst was gewesen sein. Eventuel ein anderes ähnliches Wort das zu "schier" umgeformt wurde.

Comment: Hmm. Glänzend, hell? http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GS07820#XGS07820

Comment: Oha... "schier unmöglich" habe ich immer als "gänzlich unmöglich" verstanden, nicht als "fast" oder "nahezu".

Comment: Good point @Em1. I have more to say about this in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grimms Wörterbuch nennt noch eine dritte Bedeutung, die mir besser zu passen scheint: *seitwärts*, *von der Seite*. Das angegebene Beispiel *er sah mich so schier an* würde man heute vielleicht mit *schief* bilden, was zu Bäumen auch gut passen würde.

Comment: Das passt auch sehr schön mit a) der Lage der Straße und b) der Umgebung zusammen! Danke dafür!

Answer (score 4):

Neue Antwort nach über fünf Jahren ...

Das [Projekt Gutenberg-DE](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/) hat die [Rügen-Märchen](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/arndt/ruegen/titlepage.html) von Ernst Moritz Arndt im Internet verfügbar gemacht. Bei den [Wort- und Sacherklärungen](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/arndt/ruegen/chap023.html) findet man (pl. = plattdeutsch)

> **schier** (pl.): klar, hell, lauter, glatt, eben. Ein schierer Baum ist also gleichmäßig gewachsen, ohne Knorren. Ein schieres Ei ist durchsichtig, nicht durch Bebrütung oder Fäulnis getrübt: wenn eine Glucke gesetzt ist, werden die Eier geschiert: man hält sie gegen ein Licht, um zu sehen, ob sie befruchtet sind.

Zitate aus den Märchen:

18. Märchen "Der Rabenstein"

> denn auf den schlanksten und schiersten Fichten, Eschen und Buchen ... baut der kluge Vogel Rabe sein Nest

19. Märchen "Mieskater Martinchen"

> von ihren Gänseeiern war nie eines schier

Siehe auch [hier](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=schier):

> schier, adj. glänzend, glatt, lauter, ganz, ein von den Norddeutschen in nd. form herübergenommenes wort, dessen eigentlich hochd. entsprechung lange verschwunden ist, vgl. scheir theil 8, sp. 2462. schier, clarus, sine fece Schottel 1398, schieren, a scheuren, purgare, clarefacere; unde schier, adj. clarus, sine fece! sed haec raro occurrunt Stieler 1768, von Adelung als vorwiegend nd. bezeichnet. vergl. auszer den unter scheir angeführten idiotiken noch Dähnert 408b. Danneil 186a. Woeste 229b. brem. wb. suppl. 286. Kehrein 1, 342. Vilmar 350. Liesenberg 194.
>
> 1. glänzend, hell, durchsichtig, weisz: en schier lasz-gaarn, ein lachsnetz mit weiten maschen. brem. wb. 4, 659; schiere eier, durchsichtige, nicht durch bebrütung oder fäulnis getrübte Schütze 4, 41. Kleemann 18c, schires wasser, klares Vilmar 350, schire melke Woeste 229b; von reiner wäsche, von weiszen zähnen Schambach 181a;

> ...

> 2. glatt: en schier fell, ene schire huud, glatte haut ohne runzeln oder flecken, eigentlich glänzende. brem. wb. 4, 660. Dähnert 408b. Danneil 186a; schir von gesigt Dähnert 408b. een schiren keerl, mit glattem gesicht. brem. wb. 4, 660; schiersnut, mensch mit glattem gesicht. Schütze 4, 41, schiersnutige deern ebenda; de hare schier maken, glatt machen, auskämmen. brem. wb. suppl. 286, schier papier Schütze 4, 41, en schier bred, ein glatt gehobeltes. ebenda. brem. wb. 4, 660, **schier holt, holz ohne äste und knorren.** ebenda. Schütze 4, 42. Danneil 186a, schieres holz Jacobsson 3, 589b. Frischbier 2, 275b. unsinnlich, in adverbialer fügung: so glatt und schier geht's in diesem leben nicht ab. Sturz 1, 248.

Answer (score 1):

Aus dem Kontext ist dies nicht 100%ig ableitbar.

Vorstellbar wären aber:

- reine Bäume ohne Büsche/Gestrüpp
- Gruppe von Bäumen gleicher Art (z. B. nur Eichen) und gleichem Schnitt (der Krone)
- sehr gepflegte, tadellose Bäume

Answer (score 1):

Die zweite angegebene (norddeutsche?) Bedeutung ‚rein, unvermischt‘ findet sich bspw. in „Gutes Brot schmeckt auch schier, also ohne Butter und Wurst“. Schiere Bäume sind also ohne Beiwerk – das können wie von @Syc vermutet Büsche sein, aber auch Blätter oder Äste oder Menschengeschaffenes wie Zäune, Galgen, Lampen, Schilder, Bänke.

Falls du in Braunschweig bist, versuch in einer kleineren Buchhandlung in der „Lokales“-Ecke ein Buch zur Geschichte der örtlichen Flur- und Straßennamen zu finden. Sowas gibt es eigentlich für jede größere deutsche Stadt (und für viele kleine).

Comment: Hier findet man Quellen: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/?title=Wikipedia:WikiProjekt_Braunschweig/Straßen_in_Braunschweig

Answer (score -1):

As Em1 points out in his comment, the example given by the OP of "nearly" is actually ambigious: it can just as easily be read as "entirely". Nevertheless the sources give both meanings for "schier", as I found on the [linguee](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=schier%20nicht) website.

I looked up "schier nicht" on purpose, and going through their examples, it seems to me every one could be read as "entirely" rather than "nearly". There is one example however which is unambigous: in Yiddish, the phrase "schier nischt" means "all but", as in "ich bin schier nischt gestorben vun hunger" which you might say if you were at a dinner party where food was served late.

Can you say this in German? It's a very idomatic expression in Yiddish, and none of the German examples I saw seemed to go there.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. You should turn your post into a new question instead.

Comment: I agree this is rather a question. – The link to linguee brought something to my attention, though. Interestingly enough, the English cognate "sheer" only means "completely" but never "almost". According to Duden, the German one means only "almost" but never "completely". But "schier unmöglich" is for many German "completely". So, how come? :D